# Check user if authenticate using social media - IdentityServer4

Tags: c#, identityserver4

My Identity Server 4 can able to authenticate by using ASP.NET Identity and Social Media (Facebook, Google)

Below the url to generate the token

> http://localhost:5105/connect/token

So it will response

```
{
    "access_token": "{Bearer Token}",
    "expires_in": 3600,
    "token_type": "Bearer"
}
```

Is that possible to add new property call `authenticate_type`? So I can know this user access by using social media or not.

Example:

If user authenticate by using Facebook

```
{
    "access_token": "{Bearer Token}",
    "expires_in": 3600,
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "authenticate_type": "Facebook"
}
```

If user authenticate by using Google

```
{
    "access_token": "{Bearer Token}",
    "expires_in": 3600,
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "authenticate_type": "Google"
}
```

and vice versa. Any idea how can be done?

Comment: You can add those additional properties in the TokenEndpoint method, in the `./Providers/ApplicationOAuthProvider.cs` file.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/individual-accounts-in-web-api

Answer (score 0):

There should be a claim called IDP in the id_token that represents the provider used.

Answer (score 0):

I would assume you already know how to get the login provider information. if not you can get it from

```
IdentityProvider = string.Join(", ",
                    (await _userManager.GetLoginsAsync(user)).Select(l => l.LoginProvider)),
```

the best way is to save this additional information is in Claims. you can modify your identity profile service by adding the above code

```
public class IdentityProfileService : IProfileService
{

    private readonly IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<ApplicationUser> _claimsFactory;
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _db;

    public IdentityProfileService(IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<ApplicationUser> claimsFactory, UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager,
        ApplicationDbContext dbContext)
    {
        _claimsFactory = claimsFactory;
        _userManager = userManager;
        _db = dbContext;
    }

    public async Task GetProfileDataAsync(ProfileDataRequestContext context)
    {
        var sub = context.Subject.GetSubjectId();
        var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(sub);
        if (user == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("");
        }

        var principal = await _claimsFactory.CreateAsync(user);
        var claims = principal.Claims.ToList();

        var login = await _userManager.GetLoginsAsync(user);
         login.Select(l => l.LoginProvider).ToList().ForEach(x => claims.Add(new Claim("authenticate_type", x)));

        context.IssuedClaims = claims;
    }

    public async Task IsActiveAsync(IsActiveContext context)
    {
        var sub = context.Subject.GetSubjectId();
        var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(sub);
        context.IsActive = user != null;
    }
}
```

dont forget to attach it to your Identity server

```
services.AddIdentityServer().AddProfileService<IdentityProfileService>();
```

Comment: Not sure why `var login` return null. Any idea?